# Exclude unused components from vue webpack bundle

Tags: vue.js, webpack, tree-shaking

I have a Vue3 app built with webpack. It consists of multiple tabs. You can enable and disable tabs with environment variables. Each tab is basically a directory. The directory holds a config file, a component file, probably additional assets, callback functions for access or menu hints, etc. In my main.js I run the following code (a bit simplified here) to load the defined tabs (I called them modules):

```js
for (const moduleName of config.modules.order) {
  const config = require(`./components/modules/${moduleName}/config.json`);
  config.name = moduleName;

  try {
    const callbacks = require(`./components/modules/${moduleName}/callbacks.js`);
    config.callbacks = callbacks;
  } catch (error) {
    console.debug('no callbacks defined');
  }

  modules.push(config);

  app.component(
    config.name,
    defineAsyncComponent(() =>
      import(`./components/modules/${config.name}/Component.vue`)
    )
  );
}
```

The problem is that unused tabs are still part of the final bundle.

I tried a lot regarding tree shaking, cleanup code after build, .. but I just cannot get those unused modules out of my bundle. Does anyone have an idea on how to get that done?

Comment: You should use [lazy route loading](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) (a.k.a. code splitting). Then Webpack will emit separate chunks for each lazy loaded route (each of your tabs) - and each chunk will be fetched by the browser only if/when the user visits the corresponding tab for the first time.